# Master detail Interactive grid in Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have created a master (Department )detail(Employee) pages in Apex19.1 both pages are interactive grids.In Department grid I create a form to add new department. I am using inbuilt Edit and delete  functionalities of IG .

When I edit or delete anything in the IG , Cant save changes  ,In debug following error I am getting

AUTHORIZATION WITH ID #11442180234008966638 NOT FOUND - return true

I dont have any custom authorization .
Signin user is apex admin.

Comment: 1. Is the department table found in the same schema as the workspace?
if not - does your apex workspace have write granted on the relevant (say HR) schema?

Comment: regarding the ID that you don't recognise: this looks like a workspace_id
query this table for details:
select * from APEX_WORKSPACES

Comment: It problem when you have two or move schema in one workspace that is why change schema to another one then try to check it.